# Timeout issue with Google Speech to text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have successfully used the asynchronous file conversion tool with both python and the gcloud tool. However, when I try and use either option with different audio files of my own i have in different formats, I get error messages. For example, I have been using a 45 second mp3 and trying this command:

```
python long.py gs://audio_001/pt2.mp3
```

The error message, I get back is below.

```
    "Waiting for operation to complete...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "long.py", line 99, in <module>
    transcribe_gcs(args.path)
    File "long.py", line 80, in transcribe_gcs
    response = operation.result(timeout=300)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py", line 
    120, in result
    raise self._exception
    google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None Unexpected state: Long- 
    running operation had neither response nor error set."
```

I changed the name of the asynchronous script and increased the timeouts to 300 seconds.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely the audio file type you’re using isn’t encoded in a supported format [1]. I’ve tried to process MP3 files myself but it always returns no results, or returns an index error (in both standard and long transcription methods). I’d recommend converting the file to FLAC or WAV - this works for me.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings